# Spring: GCP Pub / Sub dependancy issue

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-pubsub

I'm trying to use GCP pub sub for one of my Spring API's. I wanted to produce a JSON message which will be consumed from a NodeJS API elsewhere in the stack.

I've added the following dependancies BUT pubsub is not found in my project. Can anyone help me here please. Thanks!

**Dependancies added**

```
 implementation group: 'org.springframework.cloud', name: 'spring-cloud-gcp-starter-logging'
    implementation group: 'org.springframework.cloud', name: 'spring-cloud-gcp-starter-logging', version: '1.2.8.RELEASE'
    implementation platform('com.google.cloud:libraries-bom:22.0.0')
    implementation group: 'com.google.cloud:google-cloud-pubsub:1.114.2'
    implementation group: 'org.springframework.cloud', name: 'spring-cloud-gcp-starter-pubsub'
    implementation group: 'org.springframework.cloud', name: 'spring-cloud-gcp', version: '1.2.8.RELEASE', ext: 'pom'
```

Full Gradle file:

```
plugins {
    id "org.springframework.boot" version "2.5.4"
    id 'io.spring.dependency-management' version '1.0.11.RELEASE'
    id 'java'
    id "com.github.davidmc24.gradle.plugin.avro" version "1.2.0"
    id "idea"
    id 'com.google.cloud.tools.jib' version '3.0.0'
}

apply plugin: 'idea'

group 'org.example'
version '1.0'


java {
    sourceCompatibility = JavaVersion.VERSION_14
    targetCompatibility = JavaVersion.VERSION_14
}

bootBuildImage {
    imageName = "xxx/xxxx"
}

jib.from.image = 'openjdk:15-jdk-buster'
jib.to.image = 'gcr.io/xxxx/xxxxx'

ext {
    avroVersion = "1.10.1"
}

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
    jcenter()
    maven {
        url "https://packages.confluent.io/maven/"
    }
}

avro {
    createSetters = true
    fieldVisibility = "PRIVATE"
}

dependencies {
    implementation('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-data-elasticsearch')
    implementation group: 'org.springframework.boot', name: 'spring-boot-starter-data-mongodb'
    implementation group: 'org.springframework.data', name: 'spring-data-elasticsearch'
    implementation group: 'org.springframework.boot', name: 'spring-boot-starter-security'
    implementation group: 'org.springframework.security', name: 'spring-security-oauth2-client'
    implementation group: 'org.springframework.boot', name: 'spring-boot-starter-validation'
    implementation group: 'org.springframework.boot', name: 'spring-boot-starter-oauth2-resource-server'
    implementation group: 'org.springframework.boot', name: 'spring-boot-starter-cache'
    implementation("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-actuator")
    implementation group: 'org.springframework.integration', name: 'spring-integration-core', version: '5.5.3'


    implementation group: 'org.springframework.cloud', name: 'spring-cloud-gcp-starter-logging'
    implementation group: 'org.springframework.cloud', name: 'spring-cloud-gcp-starter-logging', version: '1.2.8.RELEASE'
    implementation platform('com.google.cloud:libraries-bom:22.0.0')
    implementation group: 'com.google.cloud:google-cloud-pubsub:1.114.2'
    implementation group: 'org.springframework.cloud', name: 'spring-cloud-gcp-starter-pubsub'
    implementation group: 'org.springframework.cloud', name: 'spring-cloud-gcp', version: '1.2.8.RELEASE', ext: 'pom'


    implementation group: 'com.amazonaws', name: 'aws-java-sdk', version: '1.11.860'
    implementation group: 'com.mashape.unirest', name: 'unirest-java', version: '1.4.9'
    implementation group: 'io.springfox', name: 'springfox-swagger-ui', version: '3.0.0'
    implementation group: 'io.springfox', name: 'springfox-boot-starter', version: '3.0.0'

    implementation group: 'javax.validation', name: 'validation-api', version: '2.0.1.Final'
    implementation group: 'com.fasterxml.jackson.datatype', name: 'jackson-datatype-jsr310', version: '2.12.3'
    implementation group: 'com.fasterxml.jackson.core', name: 'jackson-core', version: '2.12.3'
    implementation group: 'io.jsonwebtoken', name: 'jjwt', version: '0.9.1'
    implementation group: 'org.openapitools', name: 'jackson-databind-nullable', version: '0.2.1'

    implementation group: 'commons-io', name: 'commons-io', version: '2.6'
    implementation group: 'org.apache.commons', name: 'commons-collections4', version: '4.4'
    implementation group: 'org.apache.commons', name: 'commons-lang3', version: '3.11'

    implementation group: 'com.auth0', name: 'java-jwt', version: '3.12.0'


    implementation "org.apache.avro:avro:1.10.1"
    implementation "org.apache.avro:avro:${avroVersion}"

    implementation 'org.projectlombok:lombok:1.18.20'
    annotationProcessor 'org.projectlombok:lombok:1.18.20'

    implementation 'com.amazonaws:aws-java-sdk-s3'
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web'

    testImplementation group: 'junit', name: 'junit', version: '4.12'
    testImplementation 'org.projectlombok:lombok:1.18.20'
    testAnnotationProcessor 'org.projectlombok:lombok:1.18.20'

    testImplementation('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test') {
        exclude group: 'org.junit.vintage', module: 'junit-vintage-engine'
    }
}

jar {
    enabled = false
    manifest {
        attributes(
                'Main-Class': 'com.xxxx.TApplication'
        )
    }
    zip64 = true
    from {
        configurations.runtimeClasspath.collect { it.isDirectory() ? it : zipTree(it) }
    }
}

test {
    useJUnitPlatform()
}
```

Here is exactly whats not found via import:

```
import org.springframework.cloud.gcp.pubsub.support.converter.JacksonPubSubMessageConverter;
```

**Cannot resolve symbol pubsub**

And here is where I'm trying to use with some code:

```
@Bean
    public JacksonPubSubMessageConverter jacksonPubSubMessageConverter(ObjectMapper objectMapper) {
        return new JacksonPubSubMessageConverter(objectMapper);
    }
```

Any help would be amazing thanks

Comment: Did you enable pub/sub or billing in your project? Can you share full error output? How did you authenticate? You are using your machine or you are using GCP console?

Comment: Yup I did! I have the sdk up and running and working for other things. I THINK it might be a class in dependancies....going through it line by line now! Thanks for the response btw

Answer (score 0):

add the following dependency to your gradle file

```
implementation group: 'org.springframework.cloud', name: 'spring-cloud-gcp-pubsub'
```